# Launching a .jar in from a .app using applescript

Tags: java, applescript

i made a .jar and i wanna put in inside my resources folder in my .app, but how can i tell my main.scpt to launch something within the .app?

Thanks
- Ben

Answer (score 0):

```
open (((POSIX path of (path to me)) as string) & "Contents/Resources/AppName.jar")
```